# How do I take the value of a given key in a collection of hash-maps and create a new set where that value is the new key

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm sure I've mangled the title, which is reflective of my problem understanding this.

Supposing I had

`({:a "aye1" :b "bee1"} {:a "aye2" :b "bee2"})`

how would one get

```
{:aye1 {:a "aye1" :b "bee1"} 
 :aye2 {:a "aye2" :b "bee2"}}
```

I have a collection of hash-maps and I want to make a value in them the key, as shown, as well as remove duplicate entries of the same value for that key. Making the value for the key the new key is so that I can look up the hash-maps easily.

Answer (score 3):

If you are assuming, that there is always a unique key in your list of maps, you can extract the key via the keyword.  This will give you a map, that is accessed by the value of `:a`:

```
(into {} (map (juxt :a identity)) [{:a "aye1" :b "bee1"} {:a "aye2" :b "bee2"}])
; ⇒ {"aye1" {:a "aye1", :b "bee1"}, "aye2" {:a "aye2", :b "bee2"}}
```

Comment: The return value of this is what I am looking for. I realize I neglected to mention in the original post that I meant for it to all end up in a hash-set, to resolve the duplicate key issue... though I'll have to play with that.

Comment: This is so succinct... staring at it and amazed.

Answer (score 1):

You need `group-by`:

```
(def data [{:a "aye1" :b "bee1"} {:a "aye2" :b "bee2"}] )

(group-by :a data) => 
  {"aye1" [{:a "aye1", :b "bee1"}], 
   "aye2" [{:a "aye2", :b "bee2"}]}
```

Please see [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), and especially study the [Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet).

Note that the keys in the result are unchanged (strings), not keywords like your original question.  If you want to convert them, you could use [the map-keys function](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.201/api/tupelo.core#map-keys) or similar.

---

**Update**

Please also [see the grab function](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#map-value-lookup).  In case of typos or other missing keys, it will throw an exception so you can detect the error (instead of silently returning `nil`):

```
(grab k m)
  "A fail-fast version of keyword/map lookup.  When invoked as (grab :the-key the-map),
   returns the value associated with :the-key as for (clojure.core/get the-map :the-key).
   Throws an Exception if :the-key is not present in the-map."

(def sidekicks {:batman "robin" :clark "lois"})
(grab :batman sidekicks)
;=> "robin"

(grab :spiderman sidekicks)
;=> IllegalArgumentException Key not present in map:
map : {:batman "robin", :clark "lois"}
keys: [:spiderman]
```

Comment: It's fine to point out that something like map-keys will make the keys into strings, but I'd suggest also mentioning that it is probably a bad idea to do so. Many beginners try to make every map key a keyword, but there's no reason to do that. If your data was a string, it should probably stay a string.

Comment: Thank you... I really appreciate tips like this... I know I'm getting into all kinds of anti-patterns and I do want to know.

Comment: Although, the goal is to be able to look up values like (:foo {:biz "yay :foo "bar}) which is convenient.

Comment: The grab function... wow... hadn't heard of that. Definitely good one in the toolbelt!

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the key in anyway you want while doing the grouping.  E.g. using `(comp keyword :a)`:

```clj
(def data [{:a "aye1" :b "bee1"} {:a "aye2" :b "bee2"}] )

(group-by (comp keyword :a) data)
=>
{:aye1 [{:a "aye1", :b "bee1"}],
 :aye2 [{:a "aye2", :b "bee2"}]}
```